# How is it possible to filter a list of directories via "directory-exists?"?

Tags: scheme, racket

I recently discovered a strange behaviour of racket: Whenever I try to filter a list of directories created via `directory-list` my REPL returns me an empty list, but when I try the same with an quasiquoted list my REPL returns a correctly filtered list.

**My questions is now:** Why it's impossible to filter a list of directories via `directory-exists?` and how it's possible to list **only directories** in racket?

---

**Some examples:**

When I use `directory-exists?` in combination with `filter` and `directory-list` the REPL returns me everytime an empty list:

```
(filter directory-exists? (map path->complete-path 
                               (directory-list (expand-user-path "~"))))
;; '()
```

Now, when I filter an quasiquoted list like in the following example. The REPL returns a correct filtered list, with all existing directories (without the imaginary directory `~/blablubb`)

```
(filter directory-exists? 
        (map path->complete-path `(,(path->complete-path (expand-user-path "~/documents")) 
                                   ,(expand-user-path "~/blablubb" )))) 
;; '(#<path:/home/niklas/documents>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`directory-list` returns relative paths by default, which are later implicitly resolved with respect to the `(current-directory)`, which might be different from the directory you passed to `directory-list`.

Kind of like this:

```
~ $ ls dir
file1 subdir2
~ $ cat file1
cat: file1: No such file or directory
```

From the current directory, the file is at path `dir/file1`, not just `file1`.

One solution is to ask `directory-list` to include the directory in the paths returned:

```
(directory-list the-dir #:build? #t)
```

Then if `the-dir` is a complete path, the results will also be complete paths.

Comment: Thank you very much! I marked your comment as the correct answer, because that is exactly how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW running your snippet

```
(filter directory-exists? 
   (map path->complete-path 
      (directory-list (expand-user-path "~"))))
```

on OS X gives me a list of directories.

You are clearly seeing something else.

Two questions:

```
   1. What is the result of:

   (map path->complete-path 
      (directory-list (expand-user-path "~"))))


   2. Which OS are you using?
```

Comment: The result is: '() in the Geiser REPL (in Emacs) and a list of directories in the racket REPL (in my shell). So I would conclude that my problem is a specific problem with my Emacs/Geiser setup. Nevertheless I use Gentoo as my OS.

Comment: I think, I have found the solution to my problem. I used somewhere in my script the problematic function definition: ``(define (.. path) ... )`` to get the dirname (``..``) of a path. After I renamed the function to somewhatelse the Geiser REPL shows me all the time the correct output. But nevertheless thanks for your answer. It had really helped me because you let me realize, that my problem was rooted in my setup. Have a nice day! (+1)